# LoadNib from parent in UIViewParent - UIViewChild relation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib, nib

Let's assume we've got 2 classes

```
UIViewParent :UIView
UIViewChild : UIViewParent
```

as well as `UIViewParent.xib`

How to load `UIViewChild` usig `UIViewParent.xib`?

So far I tried:

```
UIViewChild *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([UIViewParent class]) owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```

but I'am unable to call `UIViewChild` methods, it's identified as `UIViewParent` class.

@Edit

```
@interface UIViewParent : UIView
@end

@interface UIViewChild : UIViewParent
- (void)someChildMethod;
@end

@implementation UIViewChild
- (void)someChildMethod{}
@end
```

`UIViewParent.xib` is `UIViewParent class`

Now somewhere in ViewController I'm trying to do:

```
//Here is question HOW to get view with Parent.xib
UIViewChild *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([UIViewParent class]) owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];

[view someChildMethod]; //Crash because view is identified as UIViewParent not UIViewChild
[self.stackView addArrangedSubview:view];
```

I have no idea how to describe it simpler.

Comment: Can't get you correctly add some description

Comment: @Ragul - answer edited. Is it clear now?

Comment: Do you have separate class for every view ?

Comment: @PiotrGawłowski With nib you can't do inheritance, as when you are loading the xib, the parent class attached to it get initialised which child can acquire, but you can achieve it if you init parent nib in child and access to its property through child.

Comment: @Ragul - I'm trying to archieve one .xib multiple class with possiblity to access it's outlets.

Comment: You can't use multiple class for a single xib.

Comment: @iphonic - so you're saying to initialize property parent and then in stackView user the parent property? As well as in custom methods to set parent outlets via self.parent.outlet ?

Comment: @Ragul - event with inheritance?